# How should guitar strumming patterns be represented in music notation?

Tags: notation, sheet-music, acoustic-guitar, engraving, strumming

I am new to sheet music and I am basically a programmer. I am trying to blend technology with music and display the tabs on the screen like so for [my son's YouTube channel.](https://youtu.be/DwMPfkElcfE)  Now I want to integrate strumming patterns as well.

I can get lead tabs right, but guitar strumming patterns are hard to create in tablature.  I created a sheet music for the single guitar strum [audio](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1X-1SFaPZTqPtIpIbv1MGAWcp-8ttoQ9Z/view?usp=sharing) like so. This is as close as I can get. But seems I am way off course. How can I get more accurate at strumming on music sheet close to the actual?

[image]

Comment: Are you asking about the notes, the rhythm, or the notation itself? Just know, questions involving transcribing from audio are off-topic here.

Comment: Agreed, @seccpur, it will help if you clarify what you're concerned about. But I spot one issue: Although your measure contains 4 beats, they're beamed unusually. I can't access the audio at the moment, but if the note values here are really what you intend, you would want to re-do the beams so that every beam is contained within one beat.

Comment: @Aaron: The notation seems incorrect wrt the audio. Its just a pattern ( 4 sec audio) not not about transcribing. I am having difficulty picking up strumming, and I thought music sheet can perhaps give me more insight.

Comment: @AndyBonner: Need more elaboration. the up strums are eighth note I guest. I have tried all permutations, but don't seem to get it right.

Comment: @seccpur Thanks, but it still needs a bit more clarity. Maybe your question is one of these: 1) "How can I get more accurate at strumming the rhythm I intend?"; 2) "Is this an accurate transcription of what I recorded? (this one would be off-topic); 3) "What rules govern the beaming of rhythms?"

Comment: @AndyBonner: sl# 1 is exactly that I want. Thnaks.

Comment: The issue you're going to run into with this question is that it requires figuring out what's happening in the audio. That's considered "transcription" for the purposes of this site. A question like "Is there a standard strumming pattern for this rhythm?", that just relies on your notation, would pass muster IMO. You could still include the audio as a reference point.

Comment: @Aaron: That was very kind of you. I joined this site today. I see stack-exchange has the best way to interact with gurus and for self learning. Posting a sample of the audio is another issue here.

Comment: @seccpur Thanks, and you can edit the question itself to clarify. One catch to your situation is that Stack Exchange is not primarily a place to get personal, general help, but to get answers to specific questions, maybe ones that could help someone else in the future. Meanwhile, I'll say that the very best advice for practicing rhythms is 1) use a metronome (or drum machine or backing track with adjustable tempo) and 2) start slow. Like half speed, and then work your way up faster.

Comment: @AndyBonner: I have modified the question. Thanks anyways.

Comment: @seccpur "...I have tried all permutations..." perhaps try different _meters_. You have aurally identified a dotted rhythm and notated it in 4/4. But, what does the rhythm sound like if you put a similar rhythm into, for example, 6/8 or 9/8 time? Notice how I'm not transcribing? I'm not entirely sure what rhythm you want. Maybe try again and let us know what you can sort out.

Comment: Just to be sure, your question is about *writing* sheet music, not how to play the instrument?

Comment: @Aaron: Yes. I am able to strum but I can't draw well on the music sheet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two standard notations for guitar strumming: one for general use, and one primarily for instructional use.

#### Up/Down bowing notations

These symbols come from bowed string instruments, representing up and down strokes, and have been adopted by guitar writers as well. This is the standard notation.

- The open, inverted box [image: downbow symbol] represents a down-stroke.
- The `V` shape [image: upbow symbol] represents an up-stroke.

[image: Bowing symbols used for guitar strumming]
([IMAGE SOURCE](https://www.fachords.com/blog2017/how-read-music-guitar/))

These notations are also discussed in

- [Reading strumming patterns for sheet music](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/95835/70803)
- [What is the symbol above this note?](https://music.stackexchange.com/a/116306/70803)

#### Up/Down Arrows

These mean exactly the same thing as the up/down bowing notations, just different symbols. Arrows are used primarily in guitar instruction materials, such as the below image.

[image: Arrows used to indicate strumming]
([IMAGE SOURCE](https://www.musikalessons.com/blog/2017/02/how-to-read-strumming-patterns/))

Sometimes arrows (above the notation) are used in conjunction with the letters `U` (up) and `D` (down) (below the notation).

`U` for up; `D` for down. Again, these are used more for instruction, and typically in conjunction with arrows.

Answer (score 2):

What follows is based on the notation example given, not a transcription of the audio.

The way your example is beamed makes it very hard to read the rhythm, because it obscures the beat, and because up/down strumming coincides with beats, it's especially hard to place the strumming motions.

Re-beam it first so you can see beats in 4/4 time. Strumming should be down on down beats and up between beats. But, because there are sixteenth rhythms, you should divide the up/down strokes again. In other words, put down strokes on the *eighth note* level, then use up strokes between eighth note divisions of the beat. Using violin bow direction marks for up/down...

[image]

...the rhythm then is...

[image]

To get the feel of the timing trying thinking of "silent" down strokes where you bring your strumming hand down without actually strumming the strings - swing your hand/arm just a bit above the strings. If those "silent" strums are put in parenthesis, it looks like this...

[image]

You could play those "silent" down strokes with an actual strum in the beginning, and then when you get the feel for the timing of the upstrokes make them truly silent. The end goal is to have your hand/arm moving evenly up/down, sort of like a pendulum and either strumming the strings or silent depending on the specific strum. Also, try counting the beat *out loud* as soon as you can coordinate it with the strum. That will really help tighten up your timing and rhythm.